# How to find A in an exponential sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I have the following formula:

X<sub>n</sub> = X<sub>n-1</sub> + X<sub>n-1</sub>A

What is the formula to calculate A given the values of X<sub>0</sub>, ΣX<sub>n</sub> and n

Comment: There is no simple formula for computing $A$. If you clean up your symbols and names you have $X_k=(1+A)^k X_0$ and you will end with computing $r$ from the sum formula for the truncated geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** we have  $$ X_1=X_0+AX_0$$
$$ X_2=X_1+AX_1$$
$$ X_3=X_2+AX_2$$
$$ \vdots \quad =\vdots\quad + \quad \vdots$$
$$ X_{n-1}=X_{n-2}+AX_{n-2}$$
$$ X_n=X_{n-1}+AX_{n-1}$$

Adding all the above equations, then terms in the right hand side will cancel terms in the left hand side. You will finally end up with equation in  $X_0$, $\sum_{i=0}^nX_i$ and  $A$.

Comment: Thanks, when I do this I end up with X<sub>N</sub> = X<sub>0</sub> + A(∑ni=0Xi) - but I don't know the value for XN - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At first please  use  [MathJAx](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) when typing,  so you may write   X_n for  X<sub>n  however it mush be between two $ signs.